Any (optimal) way to get DOM element of a script module from the module?
I have the following:
<script type="module">

// some code here to get the <script>'s DOM reference

</script>

Is it possible?
There could be any number scripts like that. I'd like to insert HTML after the script without an explicit reference.

Is it possible? doesn't seem to be. Does it matter?

@JaromandaX i'd like to insert HTML after the script without an explicit reference

document.currentScript doesn't work for modules, MDN suggests to "use import.meta instead." But with that, you can only get the url of a script element (which you could in theory use to try and select the element, using an attribute selector), but for inline scripts this will only return the URL of the embedding document itself.

I guess you'll need an explicit reference :p

Looks like a valid question to me, why does anybody want to close it?

While the question is valid already, you might be able to improve it by giving some example uses cases that cannot easily be solved by a different approach. (Not sure whether this is an XY problem - probably not, there's definitely valid uses for this Y, but you still should state the X)

Might also be worth specifying if you need to do this only from the "main" module or also from its dependencies, and if so, what should happen when one such dependency has already been loaded by a previous module. (While noting that even the "main" module could already have been loaded by another script's dependencies)

@Kaiido seems there's no easy way to handle that. i would say there could be a global function that executed in the inline module. it could somehow  extract variables from scripts and compare them to the local ones with the same name and deduct which script contains the local ones... anyway i guess i found another approach but the question itself and suggestions in the comments are interesting

So maybe you could at least narrow your question down to inline module scripts? Because from external ones I don't think it'll ever be possible (short of building your own module graph). From an inline one, you could e.g insert a pseudo-random comment into your script and search for that comment in the markdown in order to find the correct element.

@Kaiido yes, i know i can provide some key. thought there could be a way without it

Some readings: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1013

You can use a classic <script> to define some globals and then rely on the fact that <script type="module">'s defer by default, meaning they will execute in order after all the document has been fully parsed, but before DOMContentLoaded has fired.
This code is only meant to give you a general idea of how you can do this without providing explicit identifiers to your script tags via some data- attribute that you could then run document.querySelector on.
Example repo on GitHub.
NOTE: You should just copy/paste what is in the snippet and run against a web server to see it work, or see it on GitHub pages. I think the snippets environment is not fully supportive of ES modules.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var counted = 1
            var script = null
        </script>
        <p>content before first module script</p>
        <script type="module">
            script = document.scripts[counted++]
            script.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<p>inserted after ${counted - 1} module script</p>`)
        </script>
        <p>content after first module script</p>
        <script type="module">
            script = document.scripts[counted++]
            script.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<p>inserted after ${counted - 1} module script</p>`)
        </script>
        <p>content after second module script</p>
        <script type="module">
            script = document.scripts[counted++]
            script.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<p>inserted after ${counted - 1} module script</p>`)
        </script>
        <p>content after third module script</p>
    </body>
</html>




not perfect, but definitely earns a reward

Not perfect by any stretch of the imagination, but thanks for accepting.
